# Best way to apply boot options

Tags: boot, grub2, apic

I need to boot my computer with nolapic noapic and acpi=off. I can do it with the liveCD but unless the flags are applied at boot on the harddrive the kernel panics and the system doesn't boot (so no graphics tools to install). What's the best way to apply these settings on a fresh installation. I used to chroot into the install and tag them that way. For the last two releases I've not been able to do this :(.

Comment: Hold down the Shift key to make the grub menu appear. That's the usual way to apply boot options.

Comment: yes, but that is temporary. You need to make the edits to apply them to the default boot options.

Answer (score 0):

If it will not boot at all after the install, first go ahead and do the install.

Then, before rebooting or from a live CD, mount the install and make the adjustments.

First mount your Ubuntu partition at /mnt, I am assuming /dev/sda1, adjust accordingly

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Edit `/etc/default/grub` in the /mnt partition

```
gksu gedit /mnt/etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line with boot options

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"

Add in your options

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios acpi=off"
```

Update grub. Again I am assuming you are installing grub into the first hard drive.

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Comment: yes, yes, that's what I meant... deleting it now as you edited